# how to checkall and delete using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am using checkall box for check all and deleting the content.
Manual selecting and deleting works fine but I don't have any idea for checking all the values after checking in checkall and delete those items.
Does anybody have an idea?

```
   <div class="col-md-10  mail-right-box">
        <div class="mail-options-nav">
            <div class="input-group select-all" >
                                    <span class="input-group-addon disabled">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" <?php if($pagetitle=="Trash") echo "disabled"?>>
                                    </span>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle <?php if($pagetitle=="Trash") echo "disabled"?>" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
            <div class="btn-group mail-options">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger <?php if($pagetitle=="Trash") echo "disabled"?>" id="deleteButton"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" ></i> Delete</a>
            </div>
            <div class="mails">
            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                <th></th>
                <th> Subject</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <th>Date and Time</th>
                <?php
                if(count($inMessages)>0)

                    foreach($inMessages as $m):
                        ?>
                    <!-- php if($m->from!=0 && $m->to!=1): ?> -->
                        <tr class="checkbox1" data-check="<?php echo $m->address?>"  data-to="<?php echo $m->address?>" data-id="<?php echo $m->sn?>" <?php if($m->flag==1) echo "class=\"read\""?><?php if($m->flag==0) echo "class=\"unread\""?> >
                            <td ><?php if($pagetitle!="Trash"):?><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-square-o disabled" data-id="<?php echo $m->sn?>"></i><?php endif?></td>
                            <td class="subject"><?php echo $m->subject?></td>
                            <td class="body"><?php echo $m->message?></td>

                            <td class="">
                                <?php echo $m->address?>
                                <BR/><?php echo $m->io?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="time"><?php echo $m->mdate?> <?php echo $m->mtime?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <!--  endif;?> -->
                    <?php
                    endforeach
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /Right Side mail bar -->
```

and the jquery file custom.s is:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var selectedMessages=[];    

$('.mail-right-box .mail-options-nav .input-group .input-group-addon input').click(function(){
        //alert('active');

        $('.mail-right-box .mails table tr td i').addClass('fa-square-o');
        $('.mail-right-box .mails table tr td i.fa-square-o').removeClass('active');
        //$(this).prop('checked', $(this).prop("true"));
        //$(this).addClass('test');
   /* if (this.checked) {

    }*/

});$('.mail-right-box .mails table tr td i').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');      
}); 

$('.mail-right-box .mails table tr td i.fa-square-o').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-square-o');
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('active');
    var active=$(this).parent().parent().hasClass('active');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if(active){         
        var i = selectedMessages.indexOf(id);
        if(i==-1)
            selectedMessages.push(id);      
    }
    else{       
        var i = selectedMessages.indexOf(id);
        selectedMessages.splice(i,1);
    }
});

    $('#deleteButton').click(function(e){
    var list='';
    for(var i=0;i<selectedMessages.length;i++){
        list=list+selectedMessages[i];  
        var $tr = $('tr[data-id="'+selectedMessages[i]+'"]');
        $tr.remove();
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test/delete.php',
        type: 'POST',
         data: {"points" : JSON.stringify(selectedMessages)},
        success: function(result) {
            bootbox.alert(result);                                              
        }
    });
});
```

mainly check-all code is inside

```
$('.mail-right-box .mail-options-nav .input-group .input-group-addon input').click(function(){ code.
```

Answer (score 0):

on click of delete button you are seeing `selectedMessages`, but no value is found in that. So use`map()` to get all selected checkboxes

```
var searchIDs = $(".class_name input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get(); 

selectedMessages = searchIDs;// values will be in comma saperated.
```

So now you can continue with delete. But make sure you convert comma saperated to array.

Comment: i am not getting what you are trying to say..
i am newbie

Comment: `alert(selectedMessages)` before `for()` loop n tel me what you r getting.

Comment: yes and if i put  var searchIDs = $(".mail-right-box .mail-options-nav .input-group .input-group-addon input").map(function(){
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        selectedMessages = searchIDs;
         alert(selectedMessages); it shows "on" in alert box

Comment: you donot have values for checkboxes??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93770/discussion-between-sabin-maharjan-and-niranjan-n-raju).